# What is the inner product for the dual Sobolev space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\dot{H}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the homogeneous Sobolev space formed by completion of $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions with respect to the norm $||\nabla u||_{L^2}.$ Thus the inner product on $\dot{H}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have,
$$\langle u,v\rangle = \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v$$
for any $u,v\in \dot{H}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If we consider the dual space $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n),$ then what will be the inner product on this space?